# Оптимизация производительности при отрисовке. Как работают DWM эффекты типа Aero Glass?

Tags: c++, winapi, графика, dwm

Привет.

*Предыстория: пишу что-то типа графической оболочки на чистом GDI (ну почти, немножко GDI+ ещё). Уже было много алгоритмов отрисовки, но все они были не очень, решил усовершенствовать.*

Мой текущий алгоритм отрисовки таков:

- В `WndProc` создаю static переменную типа `HBITMAP` для буферизации и приравниваю её к нулю (в `WM_SIZE` переинициализирую).
- В `WM_PAINT` получаю дескриптор контекста.
- Создаю виртуальный контекст.
- Инициализирую битмап `CreateComatibleBitmapom`-ом если он нулевой.
- `SelectObject(mem_dc, mem_bitmap)`.
- Рисую.
- `Bitblt`.
- Удаляю всё кроме битмапа.

Проблема в том, как вы поняли, что битмап не очищается, и с каждой отрисовкой на него всё накладывается слоями. Да, можно преложить в `WM_PAINT` перед главной отрисовкой использовать какой-нибудь `Rectangle`. Да, это решило бы проблему, если бы окно не было под `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow()`.

Собственно, второй вопрос (из заголовка) — в каком месте `WM_PAINT` DWM рисует свои дела? Или там всё сложнее? Тогда как быть?

Ну и ещё было бы неплохо услышать о каких-нибудь методах быстрой отрисовки на WinApi (без DirectX и прочего). Пытаюсь как-то многопоточность впихнуть но пока не придумал как.

Comment: Не совсем понятна связь между растром заднего плана (который ни как не связан с окном, судя по вашему описанию) и `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` (который работает с самим окном). Можете приложить минимальный пример, кодом, для воспроизведения проблемы?

Comment: @mega объясняю: Раньше битмап удалялся после каждой перерисовки, и создавался перед ней. Я подумал, что создавать каждый раз битмап 1920/1080 как-то не очень и решил сделать его 'static' . Проблему о накладывании "слоёв" я описал. Если "очищать" битмап в WM_PAINT, в начале, то блюр закрашивается. Вывод - DWM рисует до WM_PAINT. Что можно сделать? Может отрисовка происходит в каком-то специальном сообщении?